# String inserted into UITableView DataSource not being inserted

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

Whenever I insert an NSString return from a view into the UITableView's data source, when the call to insert the new cell is placed, the program crashes.  Below is the code:

```
- (void)insertTableObject:(NSString *)thing
{
    if (!locations) locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [locations addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", thing]];
    NSLog(@"%@", locations);
    self.tableContents = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:locations,@"", nil];
    self.sortedKeys =[[self.tableContents allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([locations count]-1) inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Below is the array printed out, and the accompanying error that takes place:

```
2013-03-23 15:06:32.433 XXX[9149:907] (
"D.C",
la
)
2013-03-23 15:06:32.439 XXX[9149:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x320852a3 0x39f1b97f 0x31fd0b75 0xc05bd 0x33ed854d 0x33ec9685 0x33ec5d55 0x33ec4d27 0x33ec1bf9 0x33ff6b27 0xbeceb 0xf6413 0x33f780c5 0x33f78077 0x33f78055 0x33f7790b 0x33f77e01 0x33ea05f1 0x33e8d801 0x33e8d11b 0x35b815a3 0x35b811d3 0x3205a173 0x3205a117 0x32058f99 0x31fcbebd 0x31fcbd49 0x35b802eb 0x33ee1301 0xb701b 0xb6f70)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Is it a problem that "la" is printing without quotes?  Could the system potentially not be seeing that entry?

Comment: Can you please post your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code?

Comment: Also show your `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsForSection` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem.  I had cells with detail views, so when it would draw the detailView index, it wasn't present.  I added a simple line to the function in the original post to add another value to the detailView array.